# Getting datas based on date is not working in aggregate mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need to get the data's between the ranges if mentioned, if not mentioned I need to return the entire data's in my collection.I already using regex method inorder to find out the data mentioned in search key param.please help me with this issue ....The params I am passing are
{
    "searchKey":"",
    "status":"In-Progress",
    "defaultAccountId":1000,
    "fromDate":"2020-03-18T05:09:22.255Z",
    "toDate":"2021-03-18T05:09:22.255Z"
}
even though I pass the date ranges I am simply getting entire data

```
async function getAll(userParam) {
    const myCustomLabels = {
        totalDocs: 'totalData',
        docs: 'data',
        hasNextPage: 'loadMore',
        totalPages: "pages",
        hasPrevPage: false,
        limit: false,
        pagingCounter: false,
        prevPage: false,
        page: false


    };

    var start = new Date(userParam.fromDate);
    var end = new Date(userParam.toDate);

    const page = userParam.page
    const options = {
        page: parseInt(page),
        sort: {
            _id: -1
        },
        limit: 50,
        customLabels: myCustomLabels
    };
    if (userParam.status == 'In-Progress') {
        var userss = User.aggregate([{ $match: { status: 'In-Progress' } },
        {
            $match:
            {
                $or: [ 
                    { 'No': { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { 'grnNo': { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "party": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "buyer": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "lotNo": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "orderNo": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "manualDcNo": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "dyeingDcNo": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "dyeingName": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "partyDcNo": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "partyDcRolls": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "weight": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "vehicleNo": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "driverName": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "deliveryReference": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "deliverTo": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "reference": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "referName": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "fabricArray.fabricName": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "fabricArray.color": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "fabricArray.dia": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "fabricArray.rolls": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "fabricArray.weight": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "fabricArray.template": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "fabricArray.remarks": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "orderHistory.type": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "orderHistory.no": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "orderHistory.rolls": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "orderHistory.weight": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "processArray.processName": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "processArray.productionWeight": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "processArray.loss": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "averageWeightLoss": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "averageWeightGain": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "createdByName": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "createdById": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "partyDcRolls": { "$gte": { $toInt: userParam.searchKey }, "$lte": { $toInt: userParam.searchKey } } },
                    { "weight": { "$gte": { $toDecimal: userParam.searchKey }, "$lte": { $toDecimal: userParam.searchKey } } },
                    { "createdDate": { "$gte": start, "$lte": end } }


                ],
                $and: [
                    { "defaultAccountId": { "$gte": parseInt(userParam.defaultAccountId), "$lte": parseInt(userParam.defaultAccountId) } },

                ],
              //  $or: []

        }}, { $project: { no: '$no', party: '$party', grnNo: '$grnNo', date: '$date', weight: '$weight', partyDcNo: '$partyDcNo', partyDcDate: '$partyDcDate', dyeingDcNo: '$dyeingDcNo', dyeingDcDate: '$dyeingDcDate', createdByName: '$createByName', createdDate: '$createdDate' } }


        ]);
        var usersss = User.aggregatePaginate(userss, options)

        return await (usersss)
    }
    else if (userParam.status == 'Completed') {
        var userss = User.aggregate([{ $match: { status: 'Completed' } },
        {
            $match:
            {
                $or: [
                    { 'No': { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { 'grnNo': { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "party": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "buyer": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "lotNo": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "orderNo": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "manualDcNo": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "dyeingDcNo": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "dyeingName": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "partyDcNo": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "partyDcRolls": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "weight": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "vehicleNo": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "driverName": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "deliveryReference": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "deliverTo": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "reference": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "referName": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "fabricArray.fabricName": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "fabricArray.color": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "fabricArray.dia": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "fabricArray.rolls": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "fabricArray.weight": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "fabricArray.template": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "fabricArray.remarks": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "orderHistory.type": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "orderHistory.no": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "orderHistory.rolls": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "orderHistory.weight": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "processArray.processName": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "processArray.productionWeight": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "processArray.loss": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "averageWeightLoss": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "averageWeightGain": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "createdByName": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "createdById": { "$regex": userParam.searchKey, "$options": "i" } },
                    { "partyDcRolls": { "$gte": parseInt(userParam.searchKey), "$lte": parseInt(userParam.searchKey) } },
                    { "weight": { "$gte": { $toDecimal: userParam.searchKey }, "$lte": { $toDecimal: userParam.searchKey } } },
                    // { "weight":{"$gte": parseDecimalNumber(userParam.searchKey),"$lte":parseDecimalNumber(userParam.searchKey)}}

                ],
                $and: [
                    { "defaultAccountId": { "$gte": parseInt(userParam.defaultAccountId), "$lte": parseInt(userParam.defaultAccountId) } },
                ],
                $or: [{ "createdDate": { "$gte": start, "$lte": end } }]
            }
        }, { $project: { no: '$no', party: '$party', grnNo: '$grnNo', date: '$date', weight: '$weight', partyDcNo: '$partyDcNo', partyDcDate: '$partyDcDate', dyeingDcNo: '$dyeingDcNo', dyeingDcDate: '$dyeingDcDate', createdByName: '$createByName', createdDate: '$createdDate' } }


        ]);
        var usersss = User.aggregatePaginate(userss, options)

        return await (usersss)
    }
}
```

Comment: i think this `{ "createdDate": { "$gte": start, "$lte": end } }`  should not be ORing, rather be ANDing

Comment: if I used that in ANDing I need to definitely pass the fromDate and toDate.....so the date ranges shuold be in ORing

Comment: no I mean `{ "createdDate": { "$gte": start, "$lte": end } }` should be something like, 
`{ "createdDate": { $and:["$gte": start, "$lte": end ]} }`,

Comment: no bro,it will return the error like"unknown top level operator $and"

Comment: yeah obviously, because query is not correct, 


    `$or: [{ },{ }, ...., { $and: [{createdAt: {"$gte": start} }, {createdAt: {"$lt": end} }] }]`